# Django OneToOneField on_delete CASCADE convention

Tags: django, postgresql, foreign-keys, django-3.1

I have these models in my code

```
class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I understand how `models.CASCADE` works in Django. If I delete an `Address` record, the corresponding `User` record would be deleted, but this is not what I want. I want the `Address` record to be deleted if the `User` record gets deleted.

I know I can accomplish that by putting the `OneToOneField` in `Address` rather than `User`, but that doesn't make sense to me from a database schema perspective because a `User` has an `Address`. An `Address` doesn't have a `User`.

I tried searching about how to force the deletion to go in the reverse way, but apparently it's not possible from all the options that Django has (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Does anyone know an alternative? Or the right way to construct the database schema otherwise?

Thank you!

Comment: probably [**`pre_delete`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#pre-delete) signal?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu - okay, thanks. this seems like a good idea although i feel it's a little weird to have an `on_delete` functionality but not use it in anyway. I also wanted to know how I can protect the `User` from getting deleted if `Address` is deleted. Should I just use `on_delete=models.PROTECT`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to specify in your obfuscation layer (orm), but at the database level you specify something like

```
,constraint usr2adr_fk
            foreign key (adr_id)
            references address(id)
            on delete set null         --<<< instead of delete
```

Just a couple FYI comments:

- 1:1 relationships are always questionable. There are times for security reasons or if you do significant analysis one some of the columns. But otherwise just move the column from the child table into the parent. Also, at the database level they are very difficult to actually enforce. You need bi-directional FKs and unique constraint on the column.
- Age is a very poor attribute. It changes annually so you need a Update to keep it current, but not all of them change at the same time. Much better to store birth date then calculate age when it is needed. No update necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I should say the models are just silly templates to illustrate a problem I had with much larger tables. `age` is just something I put in randomly, but I get your first point.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE), the `on_delete=models.CASCADE` won't delete the related object (`OneToOneField` for ex.) and the signals like `pre_delete` and `post_delete` should be used to simulate the behaviour